# Delaying sub-view rendering till associated model is fetched, when using computed properties?

Tags: ember.js

I'm trying to make this ember app, where one controller depends on another like so:

```
App.BooksController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
itemController: 'book'
});

App.BookController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
needs: 'books',
formattedPrice: function(){
    return "$"+this.get('price').toFixed(2);
}.property('price'),

imageUrl: function(){
    var img = this.get('image');
    return "http://localhost/book-store-restful-api/images/book_covers/"+img;
}.property('image')
});
```

And there is 2 routes: `#/books` and `#/books/book_id`

When I navigate to `#/books` I get a list with all the books, along with a link pointing to each individual book controller. When I click it, it works as expected some individual book information is shown. But if I would browse to 1 `#/books/book_id` (it renders inside `books` template) then the list of the books get rendered, but it looks like the subtemplate get rendered before the associated model is fetched, therefore when navigating directly, all the individual book properties are `undefined`. If I click on corresponding link after it is loaded, the data becomes available.

So in a nutshell, is there anyway to tell the `BookController` to say that it only renders the associated single book sub-view after the model data was fetched?

Comment: An `{{#if}}` statement in your templates bound to some `isLoaded` property is the easiest solution that comes to my mind. Do you need something exotic what the above won't cover? If so, could you please specify further the desired behavior?

Comment: well i need to wait till the data is fetched. With if statement the best I can do, is to not render anything if at that particular moment it is not loaded, right?

Comment: Yes. If you don't put anything into the `{{else}}` section, that is :) That's why I asked further for further details: seems like the solution needs to be tailored to the exact behavior in your case.

Comment: Yeah the if else isn't gonna work :) I need some way to stop it from rendering till the Book model is loaded. It works as expected if I navigate to it, but if I want to share link for a single book, then it wouldnt work :)

Comment: So basically this is a routing, not a rendering problem. Is that correct?

Comment: I have no idea lol Anyway I got it to work there now, by getting rid of ArrayController, and by deleting the Individual items route. And now it works as expected. Although I am not sure what implications I will have in future now that I don't have separate controller for each book?